# Accessing a windows shared folder from Linux?

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-10.04, network-share, wget

I am trying to copy a (.html) file from a Windows XP Professional shared folder onto a server running Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS.

As it's a shared folder the usual 'wget' doesn't seem to work. I suspect I'm using the wrong address style completely.

I have tried:

1. http://192.168.1.66/SharedFolder/Data.html
2. //192.168.1.66/SharedFolder/Data.html
3. smb://192.168.1.66/SharedFolder/Data.html
4. //192.168.1.66/SharedFolder/Data.html
5. 192.168.1.66/SharedFolder/Data.html

I wondered if this is even possible and if it is, could someone give me some pointers?

I've successfully pinged the Windows box from Ubuntu:

```
# ping 192.168.1.66
PING 192.168.1.66 (192.168.1.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.412 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.557 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.66: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.243 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.66: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.251 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.66: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.266 ms
```

and I can access the Windows share from every other computer on the network, however, they are all running Windows XP Professional aswell. I'm not sure if it's a problem between Ubuntu and Windows shares in general or just that my URL style is wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to use the GUI, try clicking `Places -> Connect to Server...`. For `Service Type` choose `Windows share`, and fill out the fields like so:

```
Server: 192.168.1.66
Share: SharedFolder
```

Then download your file from the window. If you want to use a command-line interface, `smbclient` uses a FTP-like interface (`get`, `put`, etc.):

```
~$ smbclient //192.168.1.66/SharedFolder
Password:
smb: \> get Data.html
```

Alternatively, you could mount the share as a CIFS filesystem:
(First, ensure that cifs-utils is installed)

```
~$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.66/SharedFolder /mnt
```

If your share requires authentication, provide the username to `smbclient` with the `-U` option, or to `mount` with `-o user=username`

Comment: The smbclient option worked a treat, is there anyway of scripting this? I need to get the file every minute or so. Can I just use a bash script with the smbclient command, then my root password followed by get Data.html? Oh, and exit to come out of the smbclient?

Comment: Storing your password anywhere is a bad idea. However, if you wanted to, you could do `smbclient -A authfile //IP/Share -c 'get Data.html'` and have your credentials stored in a file with root-only permissions (`chmod 600`). See [the manpage](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html) for details on `-A`